# observeEvent or eventReactive not working right. Im using it to only display the table when button clicked. isolate not working unless im wrong

Tags: r, shiny

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
      # check if all mandatory fields have a value
      mandatoryFilled <-
      vapply(fieldsMandatory,
             function(x) {
               !is.null(input[[x]]) && input[[x]] != ""
             },
             logical(1))
    mandatoryFilled <- all(mandatoryFilled)

    # enable/disable the submit button
    shinyjs::toggleState(id = "btn", condition = mandatoryFilled)
    observeEvent(input$btn, {
        output$inventory <- renderDataTable(result[result$lot == input$lot, ])
    })
  })
}
```

I tried isolate it was not working i am not sure if i am doing it right. both eventReactive and observeEvent are not working right. Please someone help me figure this out. input$lot is an input from the user and the input is used to display information from a datatable.

Comment: A working example would be extremely helpful.  Also, `observeEvent` should be correct to respond to a button click, so you're on the right track.

Comment: # enable/disable the submit button
shinyjs::toggleState(id = "btn", condition = mandatoryFilled)
observeEvent(input$btn, {
    output$inventory <- renderDataTable(result[result$lot == input$lot , ])
    })

Comment: I have posted an example...and the observeEvent is not working

Comment: An example is there on the post and in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

```
server <- function(input, output) {
observe({
    # check if all mandatory fields have a value
    mandatoryFilled <-
      vapply(fieldsMandatory,
             function(x) {
               !is.null(input[[x]]) && input[[x]] != ""
             },
             logical(1))
    mandatoryFilled <- all(mandatoryFilled)

    # enable/disable the submit button
    shinyjs::toggleState(id = "btn", condition = mandatoryFilled)
    observeEvent(input$btn, {
        output$inventory <- renderDataTable(result[result$lot == input$lot , ])
        })
  })
}
```

Comment: That's the code that is not working

Comment: You can edit the question to add the code in the question

Comment: I have it there already i can see it apparently y'all can't that's why i put it in the comment...But that's not the point....Does anyone know how to make that observeEvent works the way i want?

Comment: i still need help for this question...Anyone that knows how to fix my problem please help me